# Is there any benefit to getting quarries?

Tags: kittens-game

I bought about 10 quarries before last reset.  This game I bought 1.  Seems like by the time I can buy them I'm already mostly maxxed on mineral production and the steel cost of buying one makes me want to avoid the cost.

Almost every other building I build I want to max, but not this one, am I missing something?

Comment: I seem to recall them boosting coal production.  I haven't played in a while, but I think the main reason I get them is coal, which usually pays for the steel cost...

Answer (score 3):

The quarry has two effects: improving the mineral production and produce a bit of coal. Other then that, it doesn't do anything. But I found that coal was a resource I was lacking during midgame, so that's why I built quite a lot of them myself. So the mineral boost is not that necessary, but the little bit of coal is.

From the source code:

```
effects: {
    "mineralsRatio": 0.35,
    "coalPerTickBase": 0.015
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is true, but it seems like by the time the coal production offset the steel cost I'd be beyond needing the steel.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't notice that, but I didn't think about it either too. So if you think the steel is not worth building a quarry, don't build the quarry. The quarry has no other effects then these two after you built the first one (I don't think it unlocks anything, but just to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, I only get a few, more for the coal income than the minerals. Later (much much later) I get a lot so I can take kittens off mining and put them in priest. You can start doing that whenever you get excess steel though.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the Orbital Geodesy upgrade, quarries also produce uranium. I found this very useful when I couldn't build Planet Crackers fast enough to supply my Lunar Outposts.